# Traversing an HTML structure searching for attribute

Tags: javascript, traversal, tree-traversal

I have a `traverse` object containing two methods `up()` and `down()`, the goals of these methods are to loop upward or downward through the html looking for the first occurrence of specific `dataset-attribute` and if found return that element.

The "specific" `dataset-attribute` is passed as a param into the methods, for example purposes we have `data-up` and `data-down`.

```
var o1 = traverse.up(e.target,'up');
var o2 = traverse.down(e.target,'down');
```

Now the traversing up method `traverse.up(e.target,'up')` works fine since the parentNode is a one-to-one relation to the element clicked (e.target) however my problem is when trying to traverse downwards since the element clicked (e.target) may have multiple children, I would need to loop through each child and it's children, etc... searching for the `dataset-down` attribute.

**Question:** Why isn't my `traverse.down(e.target,'down')` method return the first occurrence of an HTML element with the `dataset-down` attribute?

Here is the [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/77sama3w/) demo

//HTML

```
<body>
    <div id='black'>
        <div id='red' data-up='upwards'>
            <div id='blue'>
                <div id='green'>
                    <div id='yellow'></div>
                    <div id='royalblue' data-down='downwards'></div>
                    <div id='fuscia'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
```

//JS

```
function init(){
    document.getElementById('black').addEventListener('click', handles);
}
function handles(e){
//  var o1 = traverse.up(e.target,'up');
    var o2 = traverse.down(e.target,'down');
    console.log(o2);
}
traverse={
    up:function(o,a){
        while(o.dataset[a] === undefined){
            if(o.parentNode.tagName === 'HTML') break;
            o = o.parentNode;
        }
        return o;
    },
    down:function(o,a){
        if(o.dataset[a] === undefined){
            if(o.children.length > 0){
                o.children.forEach((o)=>{
                    traverse.down(o,a);
                })
            }
            else console.log("DOES NOT HAVE CHILD");
        }
        else{
            //console.log(o) **this does return the correct element with the data-down attribute however the return statement below isn't returning it back to the original caller.
            return o;
        }
    }
};
NodeList.prototype.forEach = HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
document.onreadystatechange=()=>(document.readyState === 'interactive') ? init() : null;
```

Comment: You should probably `return traverse.down(o,a);`  Or figure out what to do if multiple child elements contain the data- attribute you're after.

Comment: @James just tried adding return in the forEach, still logs `undefined`

Comment: Yeah.  Most of the children won't have it.  So detect if any do, and return those ones.

Comment: Have you thought about using nextElementSibling?

Comment: @James yea thats exactly what I'm doing, if it doesn't have the `dataset-attribute` check for children, if children loop again else do nothing, else if element does have `dataset-attribute` then `return o`

Comment: @Dexter yea I did think of using that but if you just run `forEach` over the children it's doing the same thing.

Comment: Except with nextElementSibling, it ignores text.

Comment: Also, if you're not just doing this for learning experience, you could save yourself some time by not reinventing the wheel: https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/

Comment: @Dexter the `forEach` doesn't run over the text.

Comment: @JordanDavis element.children included text nodes. Just thinking of ways to speed it up. querySelectorAll is another option.

Comment: @Dexter it's not simply getting the data-attribute by it's attribute selector, it's based on closest occurrence of that attribute from the element being clicked. I would just use `querySelector()` if that were the case, not jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
if(o.children.length > 0){
    o.children.forEach((o)=>{
        var t = traverse.down(o,a);
        if (t) return t; // return the first element that matches. There might be more but we're ignoring them
    });
    // none were found
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If you add `console.log(o)` above the `return o;` in my original code the last else statement you can see that `o` is the html element containing the `data-down` attribute however doesn't return it for some reason.

Comment: I figured it out, we both were close we just didn't need to use the forEach loop the return was returning to the forEach function not the caller.

Comment: @JordanDavis Ugh - yes, I was ignoring that foreach!  makes sense though glad you figured it out.